# Is it possible to merge two simple DB queries to get a single reply containing a hash

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, key-value

in my blog-like app, i have two separate queries;

```
Select id, title, content from posts where id ='$a_post_id'
```

and

```
Select tagname, tagscore from tags where postid ='$a_post_id'
```

Since my db is hosted on a different server from my app, my major performance issue is with the server request roudabout for both the queries.
I was wondering if I can merge the two queries into a single query so that the expected output is

postdetails for '$a_post_id'= id, title, content, tags (hash of tagname, tagscore)

Something similar to a join but where the rows are asymmetrical. Or join returning hashes...

Also, this sounds like a great fix to a simple issue, but am I missing something here? Assuming that this solution is possible, are there any obvioud cons associated with it?

Comment: I meant a key value pair/object
I thought that was the terminology used in PG (HStore).

Comment: You could use [json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a JSON key/value pair is OK, you can something like this:

```
select p.id, p.title, p.content, 
       jsonb_object_agg(t.tagname, t.tagscore) as tags
from posts p
  left join tags t on t.postid = p.id
where p.id ='$a_post_id'
group by p.id;
```

The above assumes that `posts.id` is defined as the primary key

Online example: https://rextester.com/RDQX27041